# Mostrar valores de una List<string> a partir de un indice dado

Tags: c#

Tengo una consulta de la cual lleno un List con los valores de una columna llamada Cantidad, suponiendo que los valores la lista son los siguientes:

Posicion= P  valor= v

```
p    v
[0] 41
[1] 42
[2] 43
[3] 44
[4] 45
[5] 46
[6] 47
[7] 9
[8] 10
[9] 11
[10] 12
```

Y tengo una variable valor="45", y vemos que en la lista hay un valor "45" y que su indice es [4], entonces lo que quiero ahora es mostrar los valores de la lista a partir de la posición 4.
Aquí mi código:

```html
     string sql = "select * from MyTabla";
     SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
     SqlDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
       {
   array.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["Cantidad"]));
       }
       string valor= "45";
       if (array.Contains(valor))
       {
       int indice = array.IndexOf(valor);
       }
       foreach (string item in array)
       {
       //imprimir los valores del array apartir del valor de la variable indice
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes reemplazar el `foreach` por un `for` para poder acceder a través del índice.

```
           if (array.Contains(valor))
           {
             int indice = array.IndexOf(valor);
             for(int i = indice; i < array.Length;i++)
             {
              string e = array.ElementAt(i);
             //imprimir los valores del array apartir del valor de la variable indice
             }
           }
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta List<string> no tiene una definicion para Length ni para ElementAt, lo marca rojo

Comment: lo solucione asi: array.Count, Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas partir desde un índice particular podrías usar la función **[Skip](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8)**

```
foreach (string item in array.Skip(indice)) {
   // código...
}
```

O utilizar un `for`

```
for (int i = indice; i <= array.Length; i++) {
   // código...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona esta referencia:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Una vez realizado puedes utilizar este código:

```
            List<string> lst = new List<string>();

            lst.Add("10");
            lst.Add("20");
            lst.Add("30");
            lst.Add("45");
            lst.Add("60");    

            var index = lst.IndexOf("45");
            var sublist = lst.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x }).Where(item => item.Index >= index).ToList();
```

Espero que te sirva,

Saludos.